How to configure my self-hosted runner for Android?
How to configure my self-hosted runner in GitHub Enterprise so that it can run a GitHub Actions workflow and build an Android APK? I guess the workflow file will also be different as it will not use open source actions.
I searched many resources online but I am unable to find any relevant resource.

Have you read the docs?

Yes, I've read the docs. But many things are still unclear. How to add custom actions that can be used by the workflow through ARC.

Just follow the docs, they are pretty clear. no matter if you use open source actions at the beginning, you can later fork and reuse them, or write everything from scratch.
